# VBA crashing after autofill line of code

Tags: vba, excel

I have a set of code below. The "NPPA_Alive_Row" is a string = 60000. Before the autofill line, the underlying workbooks will save and close fine (I have stepped through this). However after this line, no open workbooks will close or save (I have tried calculating the workbook in question after this line at still doesn't work)

```
WB_Checking_NPPA_Alive.Sheets("NPPA_Alive").Cells(2, 81) = "=VLOOKUP(B2,NPPA_Alive.xlsx!B2:BR" & NPPA_Alive_Row & ",68)"
WB_Checking_NPPA_Alive.Worksheets("NPPA_Alive").Activate
WB_Checking_NPPA_Alive.Worksheets("NPPA_Alive").Range("CC2").Select
Range("CC2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("CC2:CC" & NPPA_Alive_Row)
```

Does anyone have any ideas to why this is?

Comment: Could you just apply the vlookup to all the cells in the first line of code you posted?

Comment: @acvbasql I have tried doing that using a for loop, but it takes far too long to compute.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more code, it's hard to say for sure.  If the file is pretty big, the processing time to calculate 60k vlookups might be what's causing the crash.  If you manually copy the vlookup down, does it crash too?

You could simplify those 4 lines of code a few ways, which may or may not help

```
Sheets("NPPA_Alive").Range(Sheets("NPPA_Alive").Cells(2, 81), Sheets("NPPA_Alive").Cells(NPPA_Alive_Row, 81)).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(B2,NPPA_Alive.xlsx!$B$2:$BR$" & NPPA_Alive_Row & ",68)"
```

or

```
WB_Checking_NPPA_Alive.Sheets("NPPA_Alive").Range("CC2:CC" & NPPA_Alive_Row).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(B2,NPPA_Alive.xlsx!$B$2:$BR$" & NPPA_Alive_Row & ",68)"
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I understand I can simplify the code (i am not very competent when it comes to VBA). However, I have solved my issue. All that was required was a simple PC restart. The issue does not occur anymore.